# What's the better practice to reuse the where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to reuse the same where queries in the 2 methods ?

```
.where(sony_alarm_tests: {ip: sony_alarm_test.ip})
.where(sony_alarm_tests: {round: sony_alarm_test.round})
.where(sony_alarm_tests: {firmware_version: sony_alarm_test.firmware_version})
```

The trouble for me is the queries depends on `.joins(:sony_alarm_test)`.

I have no idea ? Thanks

```
  def previous(event_name=self.name)
    SonyAlarmLog.joins(:sony_alarm_test)
    .where{ utc_time.lt (my{self.utc_time} - TIME_CORRECTION) }
    .where{ name =~ event_name }
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {ip: sony_alarm_test.ip})
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {round: sony_alarm_test.round})
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {firmware_version: sony_alarm_test.firmware_version})
  end

  def following(event_name=self.name)    
    SonyAlarmLog.joins(:sony_alarm_test)
    .where{ name =~ event_name }
    .where{ utc_time.gt (my{utc_time} + TIME_CORRECTION) }
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {ip: sony_alarm_test.ip})
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {round: sony_alarm_test.round})
    .where(sony_alarm_tests: {firmware_version: sony_alarm_test.firmware_version})
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scope for this.

I have taken following content from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for your explain-nation

Scoping allows you to specify commonly-used queries which can be referenced as method calls on the association objects or models. With these scopes, you can use every method previously covered such as where, joins and includes. All scope methods will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object which will allow for further methods (such as other scopes) to be called on it.

You can create a scope like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

To call this published scope we can call it by the following way

```
Post.published # => [published posts]
```

you can refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

Comment: -1 for plagiarising documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes